# Can DS manage "admin tabs" placement for a node?

Tags: 7, display-suite, entities

Is there an existing sub-module or someplace i'm not looking for Display Suite to allow me to arbitrarily place the `View, Edit, Revisions, Manage Display, Devel` tabs that appear when viewing a Node... say I want to move them to a different place in any DS template like Right or Left.

Comment: Tabs are rendered in page.tpl.php, and ds operates on the entity rendering level. So if it can be done it would be interesting to see how.

Answer (score 0):

After some looking around, I've found the following two approaches:

1. Use DS's 'dynamic field'
2. Use DS's 'preprocessor field'

**Dynamic Field**

- Create a Dynamic Field (in /admin/structure/ds/fields) for Node entities.
- Go to the 'manage display' of your content type and place the dynamic field somewhere.
- Click 'Select Content' on the field settings (through manage display)
- Select 'Page Elements'
- Select Tabs, and save

**Preprocessor Field**

Not 100% working for me right now, however just to give the basic idea:

- Create a preprocessor field in DS and add the field to your content type.
- In your template.php file, instantiate the field:

  function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    $vars['nameoffield'] = print render(menu_local_tabs());
  }

I'm currently getting some errors with the preproccessor approach, however the dynamic field approach is working fine.